# If statement and and else if statement bouth execute

Tags: c++, if-statement

hey guys I'm relatively new to programing, I'm doing the hangman exercise. my problem is after an if statement is true and activates the subsequent code the else if statement also executes. this is the problematic code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {     //cheks the letters against the control word
        if (p1_input == word[i]) {
            guess[i] = p1_input;
            cout << "TEST 1!!!!" << endl;
        }
        else if (wrong_letters.find(p1_input) == std::string::npos) {
            wrong_letters += " ";
            wrong_letters += p1_input;
            guess_num++;
            cout << "TEST 2!!!!" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

iv added the cout<<"test1"; and cout<<"test2" to make sure both code blocks execute.

cant for the life of me figure out why both the if and the else if work together.

full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

string Word_box();
//@keeps an asortment of words and picks a random one from the directory
//@return string- a random word to be used in the game

string Hangman(int);
//stores the hangman pics
//@param int- the amount of wrong guesses
//return string- the coresponding pic

int main() {
string word = Word_box();   //word to be guessed
string guess;               //user gessed word
int guess_num = 0;          //number of guesses
string wrong_letters;       //wrong letters inserted
char p1_input;              //user input

//test1
cout << word << " TEST" << endl;

//creating the guess word
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
    guess += "-";
}

//test 2
cout << guess << endl;

//insructions
cout << "\t\tHangman v1.0" << endl << endl;
cout << "Lets play a game...\nIm thinking of a word...\nTry and guess it..." << endl << endl;

//game loop
while ((word.compare(guess) != 0) && (guess_num != 8)) {
    cout << Hangman(guess_num) << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tYour wrong guesses:" << endl;
    cout << "\t[" << wrong_letters << " ]" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t" << guess << endl << endl;
    cout << "Guess please: ";
    cin >> p1_input;
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {     //cheks the letters against the control word
        if (p1_input == word[i]) {
            guess[i] = p1_input;
            cout << "TEST 1!!!!" << endl;
        }
        else if (wrong_letters.find(p1_input) == std::string::npos) {
            wrong_letters += " ";
            wrong_letters += p1_input;
            guess_num++;
            cout << "TEST 2!!!!" << endl;
        }
    }
}

//game over
cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
cout << "The word was: " << word << endl;
if (word.compare(guess) != 0) {
    cout << Hangman(7) << endl << endl;
    cout << "GAME OVER!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << Hangman(guess_num) << endl << endl;
    cout << "you win!" << endl;
}

cout << endl;
return 0;
}   //End

string Word_box() {
string game_word[10];                       //the word used in the game
srand(time(0));                             //random number generator
unsigned int rand_word = rand() % 10;       //number between 0-9

game_word[0] = "loot";
game_word[1] = "rnjesus";
game_word[2] = "dps";
game_word[3] = "troll";
game_word[4] = "skill";
game_word[5] = "mushroom";
game_word[6] = "noob";
game_word[7] = "derp";
game_word[8] = "pcmasterrace";
game_word[9] = "headshot";

return game_word[rand_word];
}

string Hangman(int guess_num) {
string hang_pic[8];         //stores the hngman pics

hang_pic[0] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n----------\n";;
hang_pic[1] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n----------\n";
hang_pic[2] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    |  -+-\n    |\n    |\n   |\n    |\n    |\n----------\n";
hang_pic[3] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    | /-+-\n    | |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n----------\n";
hang_pic[4] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    | /-+-\\\n    | |   |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n----------\n";
hang_pic[5] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    | /-+-\\\n    | | | |\n    |   |\n    |\n    |\n    |\n----------\n";
hang_pic[6] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    | /-+-\\\n    | | | |\n    |   |\n    |  |\n    |  |\n    |\n----------\n";
hang_pic[7] = "    -----\n    |   |\n    |   0\n    | /-+-\\\n    | | | |\n    |   |\n    |  | |\n    |  | |\n    |\n----------\n";

return hang_pic[guess_num];
}
```

Comment: The for loop executes for each letter in the word to guess. Each letter than is compared with the letter guessed in this round. In an 8-letter word, this will be true some times, but false some times as well.

Comment: Your logic is somewhat messed up - you want the `if` block to remain inside the `for` loop, but the `else if` block needs to be a separate `if` outside the `for loop`, and it will need to use an additional flag to find out whether a match was found in the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, maybe my hangman memories are fuzzy... But aren't you supposed to guess one LETTER at a time? And if you think you know the word you say it, which if it is wrong is counted as ONE guess? 

I would just push to an array of guessed chars, then if entry is larger than one char (aka a string) i would assume that it is a guess for the full word, so i would compare it then and only then, if correct you win, if  wrong, do the same as when a char is wrong...

Comment: added the    cout<<I<<endl; the problem is clear to me now, thanks guys

Answer (score 6):

They can both be executed, just not at the *same time*.

Add:

```
cout << i << endl;
```

at the top of the loop body to get a better understanding of the situation.

---

This is a common mistake among beginners: You're perfectly aware that it should *never* happen, yet you assume that's what actually happening. [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: added the: cout<<I<<endl; the problem is clear to me now. thanks guys